# Entity Framework PredicateBuilder : Replace variables or control's references with its values

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework and PredicateBuilder from this library : https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/

I'm constructing predicate step by step depending on user actions and some form's controls , like this :

```
   Dim pred1 = PredicateBuilder.True(Of MyObject)
   If condition1 then pred1=pred1.And(Function(t2) t2.nr>Cint(Me.TextBox1.Text))
   If Condition2 then pred1=pred1.And(function(t2) t2.Date<Cdate(Me.TextBox2.Text))
   ....
```

...
The problem is that the variable pred1 replace the Me.Textbox1.Text and Me.TextBox2.Text with its values only when the predict is used on a query.
To be more clear , if I do a messagebox.show(pred1.tostring) I get this :

```
param =>  True AndAlso ( param.nr > MyProg.Myform,Text : MyForm.Textbox1.Text.....
```

So as you can see the Me.Textbox.Text it's not replaced with its value.

But i have a situation when I need to do this replace before used in a query. ( so in place of TextBox1.Text to be the value for example 6 )
Is this possible ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

try this, is writed by the hand, I hope it works !
'edited again .. I read something about that https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/
' but I think is waste of time ..

```
Dim pred1 = PredicateBuilder.True(Of MyObject)

Dim tb1 as Integer = Cint(Me.TextBox1.Text)
Dim tb2 As Date = (Cdate(Me.TextBox2.Text)
```

'did you tried with object ?

```
Dim MyFormObject as Object
MyFormObject.tb1 = tb1
MyFormObject.tb2 = tb2

  If condition1 then pred1=pred1.And(Function(t2) Where(t2.nr > MyFormObject.tb1))
  If Condition2 then pred1=pred1.And(function(t2) Where(t2.Date < MyFormObject.tb1))
```

....

Comment: it's the same problems, now the predicate contain reference to variable's name

Comment: can you put the result of Debug.WriteLine(pred1.tostring) ? from Immediate Window ?

Comment: Ok , this is what is showing on imediate window ( I use only condition2) : param => (True AndAlso (param.date < value(MyProg.Myform+_Closure$__7+_Closure$__8).$VB$Local_tb2))

Comment: did you try : Where( t2.nr > tb1) ??   If condition1 then pred1=pred1.And(Function(t2) Where(t2.nr>tb1))

Comment: it's the same . Debug.writeline shows : param => (True AndAlso (param.nr < value(MyProg.Myform+_Closure$__7+_Closure$__8).$VB$Local_tb1))

Comment: so you need tb1 and tb2 to be first in PredicateDescription and used after that.. to access the value of them. Because in other way I can see is just a reference to variable not this value..

Comment: I want that for example if tb1 has the value 12 , the debug.writeline(pred1.tostring) to show : param => (True AndAlso (param.nr < 12)

Comment: I know that , for that reason I tell you that you must construct in other way your query

Comment: Yes , but I;m using the library in that link , and according to this , the query is constructed in this way : Dim pred1 = PredicateBuilder.True(Of MyObject)
   If condition1 then pred1=pred1.And(Function(t2) t2.nr>Cint(Me.TextBox1.Text))
   If Condition2 then pred1=pred1.And(function(t2) t2.Date<Cdate(Me.TextBox2.Text))
.........

Answer (score 0):

see this :

```
 Dim p1 As Expression(Of Func(Of Product, Boolean)), p2 As Expression(Of  _
   Func(Of Product, Boolean)), p3 As Expression(Of Func(Of Product, Boolean)), _
   p4 As Expression(Of Func(Of Product, Boolean)), bigP As Expression(Of  _
   Func(Of Product, Boolean))

 ' Sample predicate expressions
 p1 = Function(p) p.ProductName.Contains("Sir")
 p2 = Function(p) p.ProductName.Contains("Cajun")
 p3 = Function(p) p.ProductName.Contains("Louisiana")
 p4 = Function(p) p.UnitPrice > 20
 bigP = p1.Or(p2) ' Name contains "Sir" or "Cajun"
 bigP = p1.Or(p2).Or(p3) ' Name contains any of the three
 bigP = PredicateBuilder.Or(p1, p2, p3) ' Name contains any of the 3
 bigP = PredicateBuilder.Or(tests) ' OR together some tests
 bigP = p1.And(p4) ' "Sir" and price is greater than 20
 ' Name contains "Cajun" and "Lousiana" and the price is greater than 20
 bigP = PredicateBuilder.And(p2, p3, p4)
 bigP = PredicateBuilder.And(tests) ' AND together some tests
 ' Name contains either "Sir" or "Louisiana" AND price is greater than 20
 bigP = p1.Or(p3).And(p4)
 bigP = PredicateBuilder.Not(p1) ' Name does not contain "Sir"
 bigP = PredicateBuilder.True(Of Product)().And(p1) ' same as p1
 bigP = PredicateBuilder.False(Of Product)().Or(p1) ' same as p1
 ' Not useful
 bigP = PredicateBuilder.True(Of Product)().Or(p1) ' always true
 bigP = PredicateBuilder.False(Of Product)().And(p1) ' always false
```

Comment: sorry , but I'm working with this library :https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/

Comment: And maybe you misunderstand my question. I have no problems with creating or executing the predicates. I want to know how to replace variables reference or control's reference before the predicate is used. as you can see in my previous comment , when I use a variable , the predicate doesn't not contain the value but a reference to its name : param => (True AndAlso (param.date < value(MyProg.Myform+_Closure$__7+_Closure$__8).$VB$Local_tb2))

Comment: in your examples you are using constants to build the predicate. I'm using variables or control's values.